# C# Getting the focus on a button / making it active

Tags: c#, button, focus

I'm making a snake game in C# and I have a pause and play button. Problem is: these buttons are in the exact same position, so I can't click start after I have clicked pause (because it's still active)

```
private void picBreak_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  timer1.Stop();
  picBreak.Visible = false;
  picStart.Visible = true;
}

private void picStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  timer1.Start();
  picBreak.Visible = true;
  picStart.Visible = false;
  picStart.Focus = true;
}
```

The .Focus does not work and gives an error :/

ERROR = Error 1 Cannot assign to 'Focus' because it is a 'method group' C:\Users\Mave\Desktop\SnakeGame\Form1.cs 271 7 SnakeGame

Comment: Why not keep one button and rename it each time?

Comment: BTW - You're trying to focus a button you just made invisible, which wouldn't work anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Control.Focus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus.aspx) is a method, not a property.  This should be:

```
private void picStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  timer1.Start();
  picBreak.Visible = true;
  picStart.Visible = false;
  picBreak.Focus(); // Focus picBreak here?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are trying to give focus to a control that you made invisible in the previous line... also, the compiler is telling you that `Focus` is a method, and you are trying to use it as a property.

**I'd do this in a different way:**

Just one button called `btnStartPauseResume`... and in the click event:

```
private void btnStartPauseResume_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (btnStartPause.Text == "start")
    {
       btnStartPause.Text == "pause";

       // code to start the game
    }
    else if (btnStartPause.Text == "pause")
    {
       btnStartPause.Text == "resume";

       // code to pause the game
    }
    else if (btnStartPause.Text == "resume")
    {
       btnStartPause.Text == "pause";

       // code to resume the game
    }
}
```